# how to get a value from tag through xml using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

hi if i provide a logic directly like value(   `<xsl:value-of select="value"/>`)means it was fetching properly

if suppose if i m trying to fetch with some logic like

```
<xsl:variable name ="del50k" select ="(translate(substring-after(value,'&#13;'),'&#13;','~'))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(value, 1, 5), ',',substring(substring-before(value,'&#13;'),6), ',',$del50k)" />
```

for this xml

```
 <swift>
 <message>
  <block2 type="input">
  <messageType>102</messageType>
  <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>
  <messagePriority>N</messagePriority>     
</block2>
<block3>
<tag>
   <name>32</name>
   <value>praveen</value>
</tag>
<tag>
   <name>42</name>
   <value>pubby</value>
</tag>
</block3> 
<block4>
 <tag>
   <name>32A</name>
   <value>051008EUR1009.43</value>
 </tag>
<tag>
    <name>77</name>
    <value>PUBBYPRAVZ</value>
</tag>
<tag>
   <name>21</name>
   <value>UK</value>
 </tag>
 <tag>
    <name>21</name>
    <value>USA</value>
  </tag>
  <tag>
<name>50K</name>
<value>
0601/045788775099
shanmu
MENENDEZ Y PELAYOA CORUNA SPA
</value>
   </tag>
   <tag>
<name>50K</name>
<value>
0501/045788775099
Praveen
MENENDEZ Y PELAYOA CORUNA SPA
</value>
</tag>
    <tag>
      <name>76</name>
      <value>shanmu</value>
    </tag>
 </block4>
</message>
</swift>
```

`

i have applied this xslt logic like this bellow

```
<xsl:template match="swift/message/block4/tag [name='21']">     

    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>,<xsl:text/>

    <xsl:variable name="posi" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../../block4/tag [name='50K'] [position()=$posi]"/>clrf



</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template  match="/swift/message/block4/tag [name='50K']"> 
    <xsl:variable name ="del50k" select ="(translate(substring-after(value,'&#13;'),'&#13;','~'))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(value, 1, 5), ',',substring(substring-before(value,'&#13;'),6), ',',$del50k)" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

Expected result TAG 50k remaining tags are working

**UK,0601/,045788775099,shanmu~MENENDEZ Y PELAYOA CORUNA SPA
  USA,0501/,045788775099,Praveen~MENENDEZ Y PELAYOA CORUNA SPA**

Comment: It's not clear what your expected result and your actual result are. Please use more punctuation. It seems that you're saying that the expected result for the `<tag>` element whose  `<name>` is `50k` is "0601/,045788775099,shanmu~MENENDEZ Y PELAYOA CORUNA SPA". But I don't know what the next line is. Actual result?

Comment: @larsh for me getting  result as null

Comment: Probably your template is not getting applied. For that we would need to see the context from which this template is supposed to be applied; and also some of the output before and after the expected output which is coming out "null".

Comment: You should show us the complete transform.

Comment: @empo i have edited correctly can you please check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="swift/message/block4/tag [name='21']">
```

In the provided XML document there is no `tag` element whose `name` child has string value `'21'` and that (the `tag` element) is a child of a `block4` element that is a child of a `message` element that is a child of a `swift` element.

Therefore, the template isn't applied at all and the results it must produce are not produced.

Comment: novachev excuse for the inconvience ..... now i have edit xml even if i have edit also it was not executing the record what i have expected output